# Android Studio Gradle plugin errors

Tags: android, gradle

So i just wanted to creat a hello world app and this happened

Build file 'C:\Users\Yuness\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication2\build.gradle' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google
  MavenRepo

Comment: check the build.gradle file line 3 , which plugin make cause of this error .

Comment: Post build file

Comment: Please post the build file for getting a better clarity of your problem. As it is hard
 to tell exactly what is happening